# Error in event loop with Flask, gremlin python and uWSGI

Tags: flask, uwsgi, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm running into a problem when using Flask with a gremlin database (it's an Amazon Neptune database) and using uWSGI. Everything works fine in my unit tests which use the `test_client` provided by Flask. However, in production we use uWSGI and there I get the following error:

```
There is no current event loop in thread 'uWSGIWorker4Core1'.
```

My app code is creating a connection to the database before a request and assigning it to the Flask `g` object. During teardown, the database connection is removed. The error happens when the app is trying to close the connection.

```
from flask import Flask, g
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

@app.before_request
def _db_connect():
    if not hasattr(g, 'graph_conn'):
        g.graph_conn = DriverRemoteConnection(app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],'g')
        g.gg = traversal().withRemote(g.graph_conn)

# This hook ensures that the connection is closed when we've finished
# processing the request.
@app.teardown_appcontext
def _db_close(exc):
    if hasattr(g, 'graph_conn'):
        g.graph_conn.close(). # <- ERROR THROWN AT THIS LINE
        del g.graph_conn
```

the uWSGI config does use multiple threads:

```
[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:3031
manage-script-name = true
module = dogmaserver:app
processes = 4
threads = 2
offload-threads = 2
stats = 0.0.0.0:9191
```

But my understanding of how Flask's `g` object worked would be that it is all on the same thread. Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?

I'm using Flask 1.0.2, gremlinpython 3.4.11 and uWSGI 2.0.17.1.

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround by removing the `threads` configuration option in uWSGI which makes there only be a single thread per process.